# Vertical gap in Phonegap app

Tags: android, html, css, cordova

I'm developping an Android app based on Sencha Touch 2 and Phonegap Cordova.

I've got a very weird bug, as you can see on the following screenshot :

[image]

There's a vertical gap at the middle of the screen, and I can't understand where it comes from...

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Maybe you can put a red circle over what you're questioning, because it isn't obvious to me.

Comment: I added a red rectangle over the bugged zone.

Comment: Ah, I noticed the image changed as well which was more obvious but I figured it was that spot. What type of view is that in the background of the application? A web view or custom view? How are those images tiled? I'd need to see some sample code to really help you out.

Comment: It's a PhoneGap Webview. But when I access my webapp in the native Android Browser the bug occurs too. As you can see the whole page (button, text) is concerned, not only the images. I could give you my full CSS, but I'm not sure that would help you...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with any of those. First I'd recommend you try to find the source of the error. Create a simple page with just text and basic formatting. Does it reproduce the issue? If so, it is probably a phone gap issue. If not, add some simple HTML elements like tables. Keep adding a little more styling until you find what breaks it. Wish I could be more helpful, good luck.

Comment: Hi Cookster. That seems to come from my Android version. I'm under 4.1.1, that introduced new bugs in WebViews. When I set a lower targetSdkVersion, this bug disappears, but others appear (the app is slower, the transitions make the screen flickers, etc.). Let's hope it will be corrected in next Android versions. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who could have the same problem, it seems to be a bug introduced by Android 4.1.

Let's hope it will be corrected in next Android versions.